# AWS SQS --cli-input-json does not recognize attribute FifoQueue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

I'm using aws cli 1.11.102 on Windows. The following two commands give me different results:

```
aws sqs create-queue --cli-input-json "{\"QueueName\":\"JustANormal_name\",\"Attributes\":{\"FifoQueue\":\"false\"}}"
```

This gives me an error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAttributeName) when calling the CreateQueue operation: Unknown Attribute FifoQueue.
```

However I'm able to create a Fifo queue using

```
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name "Something.fifo" --attributes "{\"FifoQueue\":\"true\"}"
```

I've tried passing in other attributes in JSON format and the following line works.

```
aws sqs create-queue --cli-input-json "{\"QueueName\":\"my_team-std_queue-2\",\"Attributes\":{\"DelaySeconds\":\"10\"}}"
```

I've also verified I'm using N.Virginia for all the commands above. So I don't think the region is the problem.

--- Edit ---

Follow up with comment of John, putting FifoQueue="true" works fine. This has been added to the bug report and follow-ups go here:
[AWS bug report](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2549)

Comment: You might want to drop your details into this bug: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2549 as it looks like this should be proper behavior and it appears both the calls you mention are tagged with the proper region. At any rate, please update your question with the output of the failing command with `--debug` options attached at the end. Be sure to remove any sensitive data while doing so.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a back-end SQS bug. In the meantime, when creating non-FIFO queues, simply leave out the `FifoQueue:false` attribute.

Comment: Hi @John Rotenstein, is this a known issue or i need to create a bug report?

Comment: I've logged a bug, referring to this post.

Comment: `putting FifoQueue="true" works fine` - confirmed. Thanks for this update.